# Unable to connect to Centos 7 on VirtualBox from Putty. Getting Fatal Error Connection Refused

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ssh, centos, putty

I am currently following an online course to learn Jenkins and stuck at one point. I have searched for this issue and found that there are others who have faced the same issue. But I am unable to find the solution possibly because I am not using ethernet. Below are the things I tried.

1. Installed VM Virtual Box and set up centos CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1810 from ISO.
2. Below seen are the specifications which I chose for network.

   [image]
3. Once the Centos server is up, the ip a command shows IP as.

   [image]
4. Downloaded Putty and added this IP seen i.e. 127.0.0.1 in it with the hope to get access through putty.

   [image]

But the error I keep on seeing is

[image]

I cannot access Google from the server

[image]

I tried to have the server enabled with SSH through.

```
suo yum -y install openssh-server openssh-clients
```

But I end up seeing the response like

[image]

If we try to connect using wifi adapter i.e. without an ethernet cable is there a different process? And moreover my Lenovo laptop does not have the slot to plug in a cable.

I spent close to 2 hours to find a solution but I am still searching. Any advise will be very much welcome. Thanks!

EDIT:

Based on the link shared in the comment, I changed the Adapter 1 : Attached to as NAT.

[image]

There after based on my assumptions I tried to perform the port forwarding. I am not sure from where to get the ports.

[image]

I used Host IP as the Centos IP and Guest IP as my Virtual machine IP seen on ipconfig /all and the ports I am not aware how to get them. Can you please validate if this is in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IP address 127.0.0.1 is the localhost on the "loopback connector".  This only works for networking inside a given system.  If Putty tries to connect to 127.0.0.1, it tries to connect to the system running Putty, probably your host system.

Please read a little about [Virtualbox Networking](https://www.nakivo.com/blog/virtualbox-network-setting-guide/)

I'd go for NAT instead of a "Bridged Adaptre".

In any case, check "Cable connected".

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116891/discussion-on-answer-by-gerard-h-pille-unable-to-connect-to-centos-7-on-virtual).

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is resolved by this time but I faced the same problem.

1. I enabled the ethernet even though I was working through wi-fi.
2. Create a user & not to forget to give administrative access to it. Try to login using that created account as the IP should start something like 192... etc where root user has different id.